# Grainy looking sphere in my ray tracer

Tags: c, opengl, raytracing

I am trying to write a simple ray tracer. The final image should like this:[image] I have read stuff about it and below is what I am doing:

```
 create an empty image (to fill each pixel, via ray tracing)
 for each pixel [for each row, each column]
 create the equation of the ray emanating from our pixel
 trace() ray:
 if ray intersects SPHERE
 compute local shading (including shadow determination)
 return color;
```

Now, the scene data is like: It sets a gray sphere of radius 1 at (0,0,-3). It sets a white light source at the origin.

```
 2
 amb: 0.3 0.3 0.3
 sphere
 pos: 0.0 0.0 -3.0
 rad: 1
 dif: 0.3 0.3 0.3
 spe: 0.5 0.5 0.5
 shi: 1
 light
 pos: 0 0 0
 col: 1 1 1
```

Mine looks very weird :

[image]

```
//check ray intersection with the sphere
boolean intersectsWithSphere(struct point rayPosition, struct point rayDirection,    Sphere sp,float* t){

//float a = (rayDirection.x * rayDirection.x) + (rayDirection.y * rayDirection.y) +(rayDirection.z * rayDirection.z);
// value for a is 1 since rayDirection vector is normalized
double radius = sp.radius;
double xc = sp.position[0];
double yc =sp.position[1];
double zc =sp.position[2];

double xo = rayPosition.x;
double yo = rayPosition.y;
double zo = rayPosition.z;

double xd = rayDirection.x;
double yd = rayDirection.y;
double zd = rayDirection.z;

double b = 2 * ((xd*(xo-xc))+(yd*(yo-yc))+(zd*(zo-zc)));
double c = (xo-xc)*(xo-xc) + (yo-yc)*(yo-yc) + (zo-zc)*(zo-zc) - (radius * radius);
float D = b*b + (-4.0f)*c;

//ray does not intersect the sphere
if(D < 0 ){
    return false;
}

D = sqrt(D);
float t0 = (-b - D)/2 ;
float t1 = (-b + D)/2;

//printf("D=%f",D);
//printf(" t0=%f",t0);
//printf(" t1=%f\n",t1);

if((t0 > 0) && (t1 > 0)){
    *t = min(t0,t1);
    return true;
}
else {
    *t = 0;
    return false;
}
```

}

Below is the `trace()` function:

```
unsigned char* trace(struct point rayPosition, struct point rayDirection, Sphere * totalspheres) {

struct point tempRayPosition = rayPosition;
struct point tempRayDirection = rayDirection;
float  f=0;
float tnear = INFINITY;
boolean sphereIntersectionFound = false;
int sphereIndex = -1;
for(int i=0; i < num_spheres ; i++){
    float t = INFINITY;
    if(intersectsWithSphere(tempRayPosition,tempRayDirection,totalspheres[i],&t)){
        if(t < tnear){
            tnear = t;
            sphereIntersectionFound = true;
            sphereIndex = i;
        }
    }
}

if(sphereIndex < 0){
    //printf("No interesection found\n");
    mycolor[0] = 1;
    mycolor[1] = 1;
    mycolor[2] = 1;
    return mycolor;
}
else {
       Sphere sp = totalspheres[sphereIndex];
        //intersection point
        hitPoint[0].x = tempRayPosition.x + tempRayDirection.x * tnear;
        hitPoint[0].y = tempRayPosition.y + tempRayDirection.y * tnear;
        hitPoint[0].z = tempRayPosition.z + tempRayDirection.z * tnear;

        //normal at the intersection point
        normalAtHitPoint[0].x = (hitPoint[0].x - totalspheres[sphereIndex].position[0])/ totalspheres[sphereIndex].radius;
        normalAtHitPoint[0].y = (hitPoint[0].y - totalspheres[sphereIndex].position[1])/ totalspheres[sphereIndex].radius;
        normalAtHitPoint[0].z = (hitPoint[0].z - totalspheres[sphereIndex].position[2])/ totalspheres[sphereIndex].radius;
        normalizedNormalAtHitPoint[0] = normalize(normalAtHitPoint[0]);

        for(int j=0; j < num_lights ; j++) {

            for(int k=0; k < num_spheres ; k++){

                shadowRay[0].x = lights[j].position[0] - hitPoint[0].x;
                shadowRay[0].y = lights[j].position[1] - hitPoint[0].y;
                shadowRay[0].z = lights[j].position[2] - hitPoint[0].z;
                normalizedShadowRay[0]  = normalize(shadowRay[0]);

                //R = 2 * ( N dot L) * N - L
                reflectionRay[0].x = - 2 * dot(normalizedShadowRay[0],normalizedNormalAtHitPoint[0]) * normalizedNormalAtHitPoint[0].x +normalizedShadowRay[0].x;
                reflectionRay[0].y = - 2 * dot(normalizedShadowRay[0],normalizedNormalAtHitPoint[0]) * normalizedNormalAtHitPoint[0].y +normalizedShadowRay[0].y;
                reflectionRay[0].z = - 2 * dot(normalizedShadowRay[0],normalizedNormalAtHitPoint[0]) * normalizedNormalAtHitPoint[0].z +normalizedShadowRay[0].z;
                normalizeReflectionRay[0] = normalize(reflectionRay[0]);

                        struct point temp;
                        temp.x = hitPoint[0].x + (shadowRay[0].x * 0.0001 );
                        temp.y = hitPoint[0].y + (shadowRay[0].y * 0.0001);
                        temp.z = hitPoint[0].z + (shadowRay[0].z * 0.0001);

                        struct point ntemp = normalize(temp);
                        float f=0;
                        struct point tempHitPoint;
                        tempHitPoint.x = hitPoint[0].x + 0.001;
                        tempHitPoint.y = hitPoint[0].y + 0.001;
                        tempHitPoint.z = hitPoint[0].z + 0.001;

                        if(intersectsWithSphere(hitPoint[0],ntemp,totalspheres[k],&f)){
                        //  if(intersectsWithSphere(tempHitPoint,ntemp,totalspheres[k],&f)){
                            printf("In shadow\n");
                            float r = lights[j].color[0];                       
                            float g = lights[j].color[1];
                            float b = lights[j].color[2];
                            mycolor[0] = ambient_light[0] + r;
                            mycolor[1] = ambient_light[1] + g;
                            mycolor[2] = ambient_light[2] + b;
                            return mycolor;

                    } else {

                        // point is not is shadow , use Phong shading to determine the color of the point.      
                        //I = lightColor * (kd * (L dot N) + ks * (R dot V) ^ sh)       
                        //(for each color channel separately; note that if L dot N < 0, you should clamp L dot N to zero; same for R dot V)

                       float x = dot(normalizedShadowRay[0],normalizedNormalAtHitPoint[0]);
                       if(x < 0)
                           x = 0;

                       V[0].x = - rayDirection.x;
                       V[0].x = - rayDirection.y;
                       V[0].x = - rayDirection.z;
                       normalizedV[0] = normalize(V[0]);
                       float y = dot(normalizeReflectionRay[0],normalizedV[0]);
                       if(y < 0)
                           y = 0;
                       float ar = totalspheres[sphereIndex].color_diffuse[0] * x;
                       float br =  totalspheres[sphereIndex].color_specular[0] * pow(y,totalspheres[sphereIndex].shininess);
                       float r = lights[j].color[0] * (ar+br);
                    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                       float bg =  totalspheres[sphereIndex].color_specular[1] * pow(y,totalspheres[sphereIndex].shininess);
                       float ag = totalspheres[sphereIndex].color_diffuse[1] * x;
                       float g = lights[j].color[1] * (ag+bg);
                    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                       float bb =  totalspheres[sphereIndex].color_specular[2] * pow(y,totalspheres[sphereIndex].shininess);
                       float ab = totalspheres[sphereIndex].color_diffuse[2] * x;
                       float b = lights[j].color[2] * (ab+bb);
                        mycolor[0] =  r + ambient_light[0];
                        mycolor[1] =  g + ambient_light[1];
                        mycolor[2] =  b+ ambient_light[2];
                        return mycolor;
                        } 
                }
        }
    }           
}
```

The code calling `trace()` looks like :

```
void draw_scene()
{
//Aspect Ratio
double a = WIDTH / HEIGHT;
double angel = tan(M_PI * 0.5 * fov/ 180);
ray[0].x = 0.0;
ray[0].y = 0.0;
ray[0].z = 0.0;
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
unsigned int x,y;
float sx, sy;
for(x=0;x < WIDTH;x++)
{
    glPointSize(2.0); 
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    for(y=0;y < HEIGHT;y++)
    {
        sx = (((x + 0.5) / WIDTH) * 2.0 ) - 1;
        sy = (((y + 0.5) / HEIGHT) * 2.0 ) - 1;;
        sx  = sx * angel * a;
        sy = sy * angel;
        //set ray direction
        ray[1].x = sx;
        ray[1].y = sy;
        ray[1].z = -1;
        normalizedRayDirection[0] = normalize(ray[1]);
        unsigned char* color = trace(ray[0],normalizedRayDirection[0],spheres);
        unsigned char  x1 = color[0] * 255;
        unsigned char  y1 = color[1] * 255;
        unsigned char  z1 = color[2] * 255;
        plot_pixel(x,y,x1 %256,y1%256,z1%256);
    }
   glEnd();
   glFlush();
 }
}
```

There could be many, many problems with the code/understanding.

Comment: Try just printing black if there's a hit and white if there's none. So we can see the results and take it from there.

Comment: Also, do not use the `GL_POINTS` primitive in an attempt to cover 2x2 pixel quads. Implementations are only required to support a minimum and maximum point size of **1.0**, and `GL_POINTS` are not always square depending on certain render states. You can easily draw 2x2 squares with `glDrawPixels (...)`, which is an acceptable thing to do since you are using deprecated things like immediate mode anyway.

Comment: @Guido: No luck, I did what you suggested. The highlight due to shinniness is removed, rest is all same

Comment: @Margi Then it means that there's something wrong in the `intersectsWithSphere` function! I'll look into it more carefully now.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't taken the time to understand all your code, and I'm definitely not a graphics expert, but I believe the problem you have is called "surface acne". In this case it's probably happening because your shadow rays are intersecting with the object itself. What I did in my code to fix this is add `epsilon * hitPoint.normal` to the shadow ray origin. This effectively moves the ray away from your object a bit, so they don't intersect.

The value I'm using for epsilon is the square root of `1.19209290 * 10^-7`, as that is the square root of a constant called `EPSILON` that is defined in the particular language I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

What possible reason do you have for doing this (in the non-shadow branch of `trace (...)`):

```
V[0].x = - rayDirection.x;
V[0].x = - rayDirection.y;
V[0].x = - rayDirection.z;
```

You might as well comment out the first two computations since you write the results of each to the same component. I think you probably meant to do this instead:

```
V[0].x = - rayDirection.x;
V[0].y = - rayDirection.y;
V[0].z = - rayDirection.z;
```

That said, you should also avoid using `GL_POINT` primitives to cover a 2x2 pixel quad. Point primitives are not guaranteed to be square, and OpenGL implementations are not required to support any size other than **1.0**. In practice, most support **1.0** - **~64.0** but `glDrawPixels (...)` is a much better way of writing 2x2 pixels, since it skips primitive assembly and the above mentioned limitations. You are using immediate mode in this example anyway, so `glRasterPos (...)` and `glDrawPixels (...)` are still a valid approach.

Comment: Thanks, I didnt realize that mistake. Amended the code and still the same image. I dont really understand why I cant use GL_POINT. As I said, I am still a newbie, this is what we are supposed to use as per the started code provided by instructor.

Comment: @Margi: Ah. That is a shame. My objection to `GL_POINT` is just that it is not guaranteed to always do what you are asking it to do in this example code. Most implementations of OpenGL will allow a point size of **2.0**, but the bare minimum that any implementation of OpenGL is ***required*** to support is actually **1.0**. They also are not always square, if you have anti-aliasing or point smoothing enabled. You can probably safely ignore these details for your case, but they are portability issues to be aware of.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are implementing the formula [here](http://wiki.cgsociety.org/index.php/Ray_Sphere_Intersection), but you deviate at the end from the direction the article takes.

First the article warns that D & b can be very close in value, so that -b + D gets you a very limited number.  They suggest an alternative.

Also, you are testing that both t0 & t1 > 0.  This doesn't have to be true for you to hit the sphere, you could be inside of it (though you obviously should not be in your test scene).

Finally, I would add a test at the beginning to confirm that the direction vector is normalized.  I've messed that up more than once in my renderers.

Comment: Thanks, I checked with the article, checked for normalization. Nothing seems to be working for me.